# Kurtosis of Sum of Random Variables.

Tags: probability, statistics, reference-request

I know that when $X_i$ are independent random variables then
[wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurtosis) gives an expression for the excess kurtosis 
of $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$. When the $X_i$'s are not independent
it just gives a formula for the sum $X+Y$.

I would like to have a general formula for the excess (or simple kurtosis)
of a sum of random variables or even better for the sum of Bernoulli
0/1 random variables.

Comment: what are you asking for? a general formula for the kurtosis of a sum of bernoulli random variables that are not independent?

Comment: I guess you want to generalize the formula from wikipedia. You may try with  multinomial expansion. And for the sepecial case of Bernoulli random variables, I guess you may have some simplifications.

Comment: Do you really want to work with tensors?

Comment: I think that the general formula is $$ \sum_{(i,j,k,l)} Cokurt(X_i, X_j, X_k, X_l)$$. After that you have to work with the dependencies to get something. right ?